# Samba Domain Controller with Group Policy on Debian

Tags: debian, group-policy, samba, domain-controller

What version of Samba do I need to be able to implement as a Domain Controller with the ability to support Group Policies for Windows 7 clients on Debian Squeeze?  If I could install as a .deb it would be great, but will I need to compile this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looks like Samba 4 only](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=879467), and that version isn't in [squeeze](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&keywords=samba) or [squeeze-backports](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze-backports&keywords=samba). You may be able to backport it yourself from unstable or experimental, though.

Comment: Remember that Samba4 is alpha quality right now.